# Survey for the University of Barcelona on English Prepositions

Tags: discussion

Native speakers of English, please participate in my survey for the University of Barcelona. 
It will take max. 10 minutes of your time. https://goo.gl/forms/FwYByBcAHSKf11Ts1

Also, I believe that to say "in the train" is grammatically incorrect unless the train has crashed and you are inside it, or you are building the train and you are inside it and talking to your co-worker on the phone and refer to the train as you would do to a room or a building. You might be in a carriage, but not in the train if we are talking about a train that is in operation. Am I right? Some English speakers may say in the train, but it does not necessarily mean that it conforms with the English grammar. Is it the same in the UK and other English-speaking countries? Your answers are very important to me!

Comment: Hi Valerie - I've moved your question to meta because it seems to primarily be a solicitation for folks to fill out your survey. If you want to ask your train preposition question, be sure to include the research you have done to try to answer your question. There are a number of already answered questions on ELL about using In/on the train/bus.

Comment: The answer could be 'by'

Comment: I wouldn’t say “in the train” is “grammatically incorrect”; rather, I’d say it’s “not idiomatic.”